# What is the meaning of 出来 in 在下面一拉篮筐就能把球弹出来?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

有一位工程师甚至专门制造出一种机器，在下面一拉篮筐就能把球弹出来。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 13.

What is the meaning of 出来? To get out? Maybe a 取 is omitted? Something like 取出来? Or what?

Maybe all combinations are accepted: 把球弹出来 = 把球取出来 = 把球出来 = 把球弹取出来

?

Comment: Machine translations do a satisfactory job at translating this sentence. Try a couple out, come back and tell us what you’re struggling with.

Comment: In the last sentence I explain why I am perplexed. Are all the 4 combinations accepted and mean the same thing?

Comment: If you have multiple questions regarding the same sentence, consider merging them into a single one.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure whether I should do that.

Comment: @Konstantinos -- Can I respectfully ask whether you have passed the HSK1,2,3,&4 tests?

Comment: Yes, I have passed the HSK4 recently.

Comment: The reason I ask is because by now you should know that 把球弹出来 is parsed as 把球..弹出来 and not 把..球弹..出来. 弹出来 is therefore a single unit phrase, meaning to "flick / spring / eject, (弹)", "out, (出来)" So, yes, 弹 is a verb in this context.

Comment: Pleco dictionary beguiled me into considering these characters: 球弹 as a noun meaning ball.

Comment: 球, in a certain context, represents anything "round", (like 地球 -- Earth, which is round), and 弹, as a noun also means a "bomb", 炸弹; a "bullet", 弹丸. So, to define 球弹 as a "roundish kind of ball" is I suppose acceptable, though it "beguiled" you as it unfortunately did not fit semantically into the context of your sentence. This shows how critically it is to parse Chinese sentences correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

弹 (tán , ㄊㄢˊ) is a verb, similar to 跳, that means "bunce". 弹出来 = bunce out.

It differs from 取 is that "弹出来" is getting the ball out by mechanical means; 取, take/get, is taking/getting the ball out manually.

Answer (score 0):

One engineer even built a machine that would pop the ball out by pulling the basket underneath.
出来 is "out", not "get out". You don't need a 取 since there is already a 弹. You must and only choose one of "取" or "弹". They have the same function in the sentence.

Comment: Wait. According to Pleco dictionary, 球弹 means ball. You say that in this sentence 球 is enough for ball? In that case the 弹 should be considered a verb? But what does it mean? Dictionaries say that it means to shoot. Maybe another meaning, to eject or to send forth should be used here?

Comment: @Konstantinos Could you please cut and paste some context on 球弹 from the Pleco Dictionary?

Comment: 球弹 = PY qiúdàn, ball (in sport, incl. billiards)

Comment: I do not think 球弹 (qiu2-dan4, not qiu2-tan2) has any meaning other than "a ball-shaped bomb". I checked "billiards" with Google Translate. It can be (1) 台球 (billiard ball) and (2) 弹子 (marble, pellet) of a slingshot or a pellet gun. But there is not a word of 球弹. By the way, 弹子 is not 子弹 which is used for weapons. There is a word 胡椒球弹 in the wiki which means a Pepperball launched by a policeman with a Pepper-spray projectile.

Answer (score 0):

To get out is “出”

“出来”is mean like that “get out there ”，“出去”is mean like that “get out here ”

You can think like this “出” then “来”。“something out a place where you are not”，then “something come to a place wehere you are。” the place like “space，spacial place，room，class，hall，Basket”

Answer (score 0):

把球弹出来 = 把球取出来 = 把球出来 = 把球弹取出来, OK or not OK?

What I can say is that the following sentences are OK.

把球弹出来 = 把球给弹出来

把球取出来 = 把球给取出来

把 什么什么 给 做成 什么什么 结果。Here “把...给" is to put an objective in front of a verb to emphasize the objective. "给" is often omitted in this type of sentence.

Here "出" is not a verb as in 我出来 （I go out). As a whole, "出来" is an adverb that means a result of "outward". Therefore，把球出来 is not OK. In case you can not find an appropriate verb, use "弄" or "搞" as a universal verb as "do something" in English.

把球弹取出来, you have two verbs here "弹" (eject) and "取" (take), which is not OK.

If 把球弹取出来 means 把 球弹 取 出来 (把 球形的 炸弹 取 出来)， then it is OK. I do not think it fits the context here :-).